# Ambiguity due to implicit conversion when using a template but not with normal function

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I am trying to write a custom string class `MyString` with implicit conversion from `const char*`.

In addition to that, I want to output `MyString` via the shift operators into any `std::ostream`. Even more, I want it to output into a custom stream class that also supports the shift operators. I am trying to resolve that situation by using a template that works for `MyStream` just the same as with `std::ostream`.

However, this leads easily to ambiguity in overload resolution. The gist of the problem is summarized in the following example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct MyString
{
    // implicit constructors
    MyString( const char* cstr ) {};
    // some dummy c_str()
    const char* c_str() const { return nullptr; };
};

// // This works just fine, as expected, ...
// inline std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const MyString& str )
// {
//    std::cout << str.c_str();
//    return out;
// }

// ... but this one causes ambiguity !!!
template<typename S>
inline S& operator<<( S& out, const MyString& str )
{
    std::cout << str.c_str();
    return out;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "1";

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "2";

    std::cout << ss.str().c_str();

    return 0;
}
```

The code above works just fine. However, if instead I comment out the `std::ostream` operator overload and try to use the template instead, then the operator calls are suddenly ambiguous.

The shift into `std::cout` works but the shift into `std::stringstream ss` has become ambigious.

*Question:* what is the reason for the lack of ambiguity in the first case and its the sudden ambiguity in the second case? What possibilities are there to resolve this issue?

I want to retain the implicit conversion facility for `MyString`, and I want to shift such objects into **anything** that behaves like the standard stream, using the shift operators.

EDIT: Whether it compiles or not depends on the compiler's strictness. On https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler I get

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:33:11: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
   33 |     ss << "2";
      |           ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/ostream:611:5: note: candidate 1: ‘std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*) [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
  611 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:21:11: note: candidate 2: ‘S& operator<<(S&, const MyString&) [with S = std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>]’
   21 | inline S& operator<<( S& out, const MyString& str )
      |           ^~~~~~~~
12
```

Comment: `inline std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const MyString& str )` will already work with any type that accepts an `ostream&`, which is the canonical approach.  Making the left hand side of your operator a template makes it greaddy and it'll match everything.  You'd need to constrain `S` to not be any of the library stream types.

Comment: Your `operator<<` accepts `out` as an argument, but then writes to `std::cout` instead of `out`.

Comment: Please show a [mre] and the full compiler error message

Comment: @AlanBirtles: that's exactly what the code above is.

Comment: @NathanPierson: right, but it's only a minimal example.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't think that really clarifies what's happening here. Why is there no ambiguity with the first output into `std::cout` but ambiguity arises with output into `ss`?

Answer (score 1):

`std::ostream` is a base type of `std::stringstream` defined as `std::basic_stringstream<char>` (see the [inheritance diagram](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)).
The instantiated function `operator<<(std::stringstream& out, const MyString& str)` conflicts with [the function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) `operator<<(std::ostream& out, const char*s)` because the compiler can't decide whether to convert the `const char*` argument to `MyString` or to upcast `std::stringstream` to `std::ostream`.

We may explicitly convert the string argument to remove the ambiguity, i.e. `ss << MyString("2");`

Update: Note that the first function called with `cout` argument is the standard function and not the expected one, because the standard function represents the exact match, https://godbolt.org/z/P46sxejr4.

I suggest to not rely on implicit conversions for the listed in the documentation types because there is always will be a better exact standard match. And I suggest to stick to [the recommended way of defining the overload](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#output-operator) to make your code less error-prone.

Comment: So upcasting is considered as bad as implicit conversion? That is very surprising.

Comment: @shuhalo fyi, here is the gcc warning: "ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second"

Comment: Shouldn't a derived-to-base class conversion, being a standard conversion, be preferred to a user-defined conversion, as by an implicit constructor?

Comment: @shuhalo we have a well-known ambiguity with a function having two arguments, both requiring conversions of some kind. The ambiguity is too subtle to infer the only right resolution.

Comment: @shuhalo • *So upcasting is considered as bad as implicit conversion?* **Unnecessary** upcasting is worse than implicit conversion. That should not be surprising.